# Groovy AST - add class annotation using enums

Tags: groovy, annotations, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to add the `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation to my classes using an AST during compile time.

The annotation to add should come out as (using class as example):

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="className")
```

Where `JsonTypeInfo.Id` is defined as:

```
public enum Id {
    NONE(null),
    CLASS("@class"),
    MINIMAL_CLASS("@c"),
    NAME("@type"),
    CUSTOM(null)
    ;
}
```

and `JsonTypeInfo.As` is defined as:

```
public enum As {
    PROPERTY,
    WRAPPER_OBJECT,
    WRAPPER_ARRAY,
    EXTERNAL_PROPERTY
    ;
}
```

both inside the `JsonTypeInfo` class.

To add the annotation, I have a function `setJson()`, like so:

```
public static void setJson(ClassNode cn)
{
    AnnotationNode an = new AnnotationNode( new ClassNode(com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo.class));

    an.addMember("use", new ConstantExpression(JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS));
    an.addMember("include", new ConstantExpression(JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY));
    an.addMember("property", new ConstantExpression("className"));

    cn.addAnnotation(an);
}
```

However, only the `property` member seems to be set without a problem. When I run for the rest, I get errors like

```
"Expected enum value for attribute use in @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo"
```

How can I properly pass in an Enum value during the AST transformation? Trying to pass the values in directly (i.e. Using `CLASS` or `1`) doesn't work.

Looking through the other `Expression` classes from here: http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/org/codehaus/groovy/ast/expr/Expression.html, I think maybe `FieldExpression` would do the job, but I've not been able to get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking in the AST browser for a class annotated with `JsonTypeInfo` (as in your example annotation above), You get:

```
use: org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.PropertyExpression@7f78be49 [
         object: org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ClassExpression@5014ec00[
                     type: com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo$Id
         ]
         property: ConstantExpression[CLASS]
     ]
```

Which leads me to believe that:

```
an.addMember("use", new ConstantExpression(JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS));
```

Should be:

```
an.addMember("use", new PropertyExpression(
                      new ClassExpression( JsonTypeInfo.Id ),
                      new ConstantExpression( JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS ) ) )
```

But I haven't tested it, and may be talking rubbish :-/

Comment: Had to modify the `ClassExpression` to take a `ClassNode`, but that's it! `an.addMember("use", new PropertyExpression(
                new ClassExpression( new ClassNode( com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo.Id.class) ),
                new ConstantExpression( JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS ) ) );`